# Как передать json из C# в Python

Tags: c#, python, python-3.x, json, потоки-данных

пожалуйста подскажите: Есть ли способ как запустить скрипт питона из С# передав(или в последствии передать) ему Json объект, и потом принять назад Json из потока вывода Python или как то еще?

Пока что изучил следующие способы, но это не решает проблемы:

1. Запуск скрипта питон на C# из командной строки
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands
2. Можно запустить скрипт python и потом передать туда json в input(), но как передать в рабочую программу json из C# Я не понимаю.

   ```
   import json
   from prompt_toolkit import prompt
   answer = prompt('Give me some input: ')
   result = json.loads(answer)
   print('You said: %s' % result)
   ```

Я пробовал писать:

```
    import sys 
    import json 
    result = json.loads(sys.stdin.read()) 
    sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(result))
```

Но не понимаю как передать в поток ввода json при запуске скрипта

Comment: ```stdin```, ```stdout```, как на счет них? Можно через именованные каналы.

Comment: @gregzakharov Можно пожалуйста по подробнее как они работают, или пример лучше полного цикла взаимодействия)) 
Я пробовал писать: *Добавил пример в вопрос*

Но не понимаю как передать в поток ввода json при запуске скрипта или как. Еще не сталкивался с потоками.

Comment: @gregzakharov про именованные каналы не слышал вообще раньше тоже было бы очень интересно

Comment: Начал было писать примеры, как задался вопросом: а для чего, собственно, передавать JSON интерпретатору Python? Разве есть в последнем то, чего нельзя сделать с JSON в .NET?

Comment: @gregzakharov Есть готовый скрипт на Python. Хотелось бы его использовать для данных которые формируются в C#.

Почитал про именованные каналы, но пока плохо понял как использовать)

Comment: @gregzakharov Я бы был очень благодарен, если бы Вы помогли с этим вопросом. Очень интересно разобраться во взаимодействии между разными программами.

Comment: В командной строчке: `c_sharp_program | python_program`: В С# программе просто печатайте в стандартный вывод (аналог `print(json_text)` или `json.dump(obj, sys.stdout)` в Питоне). В Питоне просто читайте из стандартного ввода: `obj = json.load(sys.stdin)`

Comment: @jfs буду пробовать, спасибо!